# How to configure jenkins to generate Test Results with code coverage using NCover

Tags: hudson, mstest, code-coverage, jenkins, ncover

I have installed NCover in my CI server . How can I configure jenkins to show html reports with contains test results with code coverage? 
 I have found a post but it is using something called Gallio (    http://blog.teamlazerbeez.com/2009/08/04/using-ncover-for-net-code-coverage-with-hudson/ ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finnaly I ended up with this http://codetuner.blogspot.com/2011/06/ncover-command-line-for-mstest.html